# Auto fill textbox using another textbox js

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to auto fill the second fields using my first text box? What I want is if I type number 1 the second field will have a value equal to my input. I cant find easy example in the internet its very complicated to me.

- 1 = ruby
- 2 = gold
- 3 = diamond

**CODE**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="section_number" placeholder="Enter Section Number">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="section_name">
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I find related topics but code is not close for me. Im new to javascript actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, yes you can monitor the `input` field with JS, assign the #'s/words you want to match as key/value pairs in an object, and when someone types something, see if it is a matched key in the object. If there is a match, display the value of the key in the text box.

Here's a way using jquery.

```js
var obj = {
  1:'ruby',
  2:'gold',
  3:'diamond'
}

$('#num').on('keyup',function() {
  var key = $(this).val(),
      result = obj[key],
      $text = $('#text')
  if (result != undefined) {
    $text.val(result);
  } else {
    $text.val('');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num" class="form-control" name="section_number" placeholder="Enter Section Number">
<input type="text" id="text" class="form-control" name="section_name">
```

Comment: Thank you sir, This is the one I'm looking for..

Comment: @misdirection sweet! no problemo.